# Jquery: Check against first instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having some trouble with this with taking a weird output and turning it into readable screenplay format.

So here is the HTML.

```
<div>
<p class="actor">John</p>
<p class="line">I want to buy milk.</p>
<p class="actor">John</p>
<p class="line">Milk is expensive.</p>
<p class="dirNote">John grabs the milk</p>
<p class="actor">John</p>
<p class="line">I guess its fine.</p>
<p class="actor">Steve</p>
<p class="line">Yeah.</p>
</div>
```

My attempts have solving this have failed. but the basic idea is this...

loop through each instance of p.actor
store first instance as a var

check next instance against var

if they are the same

append contents of that instance's p.line into the p.line of var

else replace var

with new p.actor

Also, if encounter a p.dirNote next instance of p.actor sets new var

basically when finished the html should look like this

```
<div>
<p class="actor">John</p>
<p class="line">I want to buy milk. Milk is expensive.</p>
<p class="dirNote">John grabs the milk</p>
<p class="actor">John</p>
<p class="line">I guess its fine.</p>
<p class="actor">Steve</p>
<p class="line">Yeah.</p>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on feasibility? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is the problem? Your JS code might also be helpful.

Comment: what about third John?

Comment: why does (John grabs the milk) if the (Milk is expensive) do you mean to say (Milk is expensive) and (John grabs the milk and runs out of the supermarket, where he gets shot by cops) :))

Comment: )))))) @TasosAnastasiou

Comment: third john is there, just to show instance where the same name occurs again, but should be it's own paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet should do trick. It basically coverts the collection into an array and starts from the last element in the set.

```
$('p.actor').toArray().reverse().forEach(function (el) {
    var 
        $this = $(el), 
        $prev = $this.prev().prev('.actor'), 
        $line
    ;

    if ($this.text() !== $prev.text()) {
        return;
    }

    $line = $this.next('.line');
    $prev.next('.line').append(' ' + $line.text());
    $this.add($line).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j9qwzyzq/

Answer (score 0):

I've got a half-answer for you. It got more evolving than I though so I'll stop for now.

It loops through your paragraphs, keeps track of their type and rebuild a new list. It still needs to figure out how to keep track of the previous (or next) line/actor and `addRow` accordantly. Hope it helps...

```
var rows = $("#my-list p"),
newRows = [],
currentActor = null,
currentLine = null,
addRow = function (type, value) {
    newRows.push({
        type: type,
        value: value
    })
};

rows.each(function (index) {
    var $row = $(this),
        className = $row.attr("class"),
        isActor = className == "actor",
        isLine = className == "line",
        isDirNote = className == "dirNote",
        content = $row.text();

    if (isLine) {
        //TODO: keep track of line to be appended to next item (if same actor)
        //TODO: if next element is same actor, append line
        //addRow(className, content);
    }
    if (isDirNote || isActor) {
        addRow(className, content);
    }
    console.log(content, isActor, isLine, isDirNote);
})

console.log(newRows);

//TODO: build new paragraph array from newRows
```