# Jquery: Different approaches to readable output; selector issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Appending HTML ...

This does what I want it to. (See how John's lines are appended to each other?)
http://jsfiddle.net/j9qwzyzq/

But this doesn't. (nothing is happening)
https://jsfiddle.net/5L1mzrxp/5/

I'm guessing the fault is in this line

```
    $p = $t.prevAll('.performer_line_performed_prefix'),
```

I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to select the variable properly.

Please help.

[Relevant Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314577/jquery-check-against-first-instance)

Comment: I think it has more to do with the mismatched spaces after "John" https://jsfiddle.net/5L1mzrxp/6/

Comment: Note that your html is invalid, `p` can't be child of another `p` element! I'm referring to `<p class="line">
            <p class="performer_line_performed_prefix">Fiona <a href='#' onclick="return playSound('');">...`

Comment: cleaning up the html did it. Thanks rob